# Nonexistence of a group homomorphism from the adeles to a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, adeles

Let $\mathbb A_K$ be the additive group of adeles associated to a number field $K$.

I suspect that there is no **surjective** group homomorpphism $\phi:\mathbb A_K\to K$  such that the kernel is of the type $b\mathbb A_K$ for $b\in \mathbb A_K\setminus 0$. Do you have any idea how to prove (or disprove) this? In particular, given an element $(a_\mathfrak p)\in \mathbb A_K$ I don't see any way to produce an element $f\in K$ that respects the sum.

Comment: $\mathbb{A}_K$ is a $K$-vector space, so “obviously” (say, using choice) there’s a linear form on this vector space. You may want to be more specific about the properties that you require.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need a specific kernel. I edited the questiion.

Comment: I suggest to study $\mathbb{A}_K/b\mathbb{A}_K$ for an arbitrary $b$. If you can show that it is never of dimension one over $K$, you’re done.